# Expired residence permit and non-EU passport. What happens if I return to Italy?

Tags: visas, schengen

I study PhD in Italy and I have a Turkish passport. My Italian residence permit is expired, I have only a postal receipt.

I visited my girlfriend living in Prague, am currently in Prague, and came here by air (with last day of my valid visa). I didn't know I can not travel with only this receipt. If I come back to Italy by train or bus and if somebody asks me a visa or proof of residence, what will happen? Can/will I be deported to Turkey?

Answer (score 1):

With *Ricevuta postale* you can only travel to your home country. Other Schengen countries don't recognize that document. If you still have a Schengen visa you, you can be in Prague and leave for Italy before it expires. At Italian border you can show your postal receipt.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond Kumar, My visa is also expired, I have just postal receipt with me, when I came to Prague I used my last day of valid visa (4th of August) so now every valid document is expired. If i try to come back Italy it is a big problem with this postal receipt on the way ?